# How to merge two text files into one file without using cat or sed

Tags: text-processing, csv, merge

I have two files

File1:

```
a
b
c
```

File2:

```
1
2
3
```

now I need to combine them to one csv file

```
a;1
b;2
c;3
```

As the files are really huge, I would rather not use `cat` and `sed` to process the second file. (For smaller files I can use a script). Any Idea ? `awk`/`perl` ?

Comment: Nitpick - CSV is *Comma* Separated Values.  I suspect many CSV utilities would reject semicolon separated values, at least with default settings.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma many utilities which are aware of locale will take semicolon separated values for certain locales, and reject the comma separated ones.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), "CSV" is commonly used to refer to files with values separated by other delimiters too. It's quite confusing.

Comment: @Anko thanks - I did not know that :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try [`paste`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) command :

```
paste -d';' File1 File2 > File3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  w[FNR][FILENAME] = $0
}
END {
  for (x in w)
    print w[x][ARGV[1]] ";" w[x][ARGV[2]]
}
```

I also came up with this, but it fails because of the way Awk iterates arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  w[FNR][FILENAME] = $0
}
END {
  for (x in w) {
    y = 0
    for (z in w[x]) {
      printf w[x][z]
      printf y ? "\n" : ";"
      y = 1
    }
  }
}
```